# Symfony2 service not registering

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

When I do `php app/console service:debug` my service is listed as expected, but when I access my bundle from web, or by functional tests - I get:

Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "xx.handler"." at xx/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2031 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service \"xx.handler\". at xx/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2031)"} []

I also attempted to type `die('di');` in the DependecyInjection Extension, which is never triggered when using the browser to access the controller, but it fires with `php app/console service:debug`

How to resolve the above error, such that accessing my controller will register my service?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`app/console cache:clear`

Also - It's better to debug your code on dev mod via app_dev.php

Comment: Clearing cache didn't help

Comment: The proper command to clear the production cache is `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`